# When to use tempfile, pickle, json or open()

Tags: python, json, pickle

I know Python has many ways of storing and reading data from files, so I would like to know what the best practices are for the above 4, and when each is most applicable.

Also, please let me know if there are any other modules/functions I should be aware of.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to do? Otherwise, I fear the scope of your question is too broad.

Comment: At least pickle and json are not used to "dump files" but to persist data *to* files.

Comment: What brought this on was the fact that I discovered the tempfile module and didn't quite know when to use it exactly. This also made me realize that you can use all 3 of these functions fairly interchangeably for many purposes, though obviously, with varying degrees of efficiency. Basically, I want to know if there is some sort of "official guideline."

Comment: There is no 'guideline' apart from use what you need. `open` is for opening reading and writing any file, `tempfile` is for creating temporary files. Yes, you can also create temporary files using `open` and pass the right path, but then you'd have to know which OS your code is running on. `json` and `pickle` belong to a totally different category. They are used to convert data into different formats. Which format to choose depends on your needs. All these commands have different purposes so it does not make sense to compare them.

Comment: Yes, I think you are all right - I think this question is way too broad for SO. Does anyone have a link to a (or multiple) good blog post(s) that might be relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i'm sure you've read the documentation of the above commands in python, but i think you're in a mistake of it's use. For file openning as you ask the open is quite good enough within a while statement.

> json -> to treat strings,lists with it's method's dumps and loads in a
>   json format of them.
>  pickle -> to serialize data 
>  tempfile
>   -> to create temporary files / directories.

But as i said previously, the best way to treat with files to dump (commands read/write) if no special treatment required just use the open, write commands.

Regards.